# How can I remove the return paths for a series of circuits and still know when they are completed? NFC/RFID? Multiplexing? Goubau line?

Tags: circuit-design, rfid, modulation, nfc, 1-wire

Apologies for the vague title. And know that my electronics knowledge is rather limited. Also my circuit diagrams may be incorrect.

I currently have something like this, which represents contacts on the thumb, and each of the four fingers:

[image]

I am simply detecting when a finger and a thumb touch, and determining what finger it was that made the touch. Easy!

Right now it works perfectly. It is reliable. I have dealt with the switch bounce. Now I want to retain the reliability/robustness while removing the wires that run to each finger.

So I want to remove wires on the fingers, and simply have a wire running to the thumb from the microcontroller, with a contact of some kind on each finger.

[image]

I feel perhaps I am over-complicating this, but these are my ideas thus far:

1. Glue micro NFC/RFID transponder to each fingertip, with the reader on the thumb.

[image]

2. Same as above, but some kind of NFC/RFID transponder which is activated from direct current rather than from a range. Does this exist?
3. I've been reading about different kinds of multiplexing which allow multiple signals to run through a single conductor, in opposing directions. My worry here is that whatever hardware this requires, might be too big to sit upon a fingertip.
4. Some kind of contact which allows current to flow both ways in a single conductor. I can send a current from the thumb, and have small resistors of different values on each fingertip, and then analyze the return current to determine which finger was touched.
5. I also read about single current earth return which allows power transmission without return lines, by grounding. Could I deliver a current from the thumb to a resister on the fingertip, then ground the current in the fingertip. And somehow listen for the grounded signal in the wrist?
6. Have fingertip pads made of materials with different conductivity, and read the conductivity of whatever material touches the thumb. This will require a return line though (I think).
7. Colored finger pads, with a color sensor on the thumb.
8. Fingerprint reader on thumb, fingers are identified by print. This might be tough given the amount of partial prints, and also latency is analysis.

I hope I have made my intentions for this rather clear. Running a single wire to the thumb from a microcontroller, and determining which finger touched the thumb contact by using some kind of wireless pad on each fingertip.

I hope my lacking knowledge in electronics has deprived me of some simple solution to this problem.

All help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No way! I knew I was overcomplicating this. Thank you so much. Any chance you could supply links to such coatings?

Comment: I had considered the armband initially, but I imagine there is quite a bit of noise. And lots of false positives.

Comment: Do you think this would be robust in real world applications? Eg. oils and moisture on the coating?

Comment: the armband would probably require some type of self learning neural network software to recognize finger movement

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: some sort of RFID on each finger and a sensor on the thumb. - that will give proximity but not touch,  or a 3d camera. or a digitising glove

Comment: Thanks for the response. If there was RFID that could be activated by touch, that would be ideal. I guess that’s just a wired transponder/antenna. Am trying to avoid a gloved solution.